# BBO crystals and Polarized photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics

I you have photon polarized in a given orientation going through a BBO crystal... what orientation will have the entangled photons going out?

Comment: See especially the * note at the bottom of the second answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172159/what-laser-and-bbo-are-needed-to-create-entangled-laser-streams

Comment: Hello, welcome to [physics.se]! If you have a question that gets closed, please don't delete and re-ask it. Instead, edit the closed question, which puts in front of reviewers who will consider re-opening it. I think this version of your question is better than [your previous effort](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/413848/revisions), and I hope you get a good [conceptual answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/).